# QtAndroid - non-static method sendMessage(String,String) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android

I knew this question may be not interesting , But I want to use string function in another function. Here is my code:

**example.java:**

```
public native String sendMessage(String jid, String message);
.
.
.
ImageButton1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         final String m_Text = EditText1.getText().toString();
         if (m_Text.length() > 0){
            notifyMessage (m_Text);                            
            String uid = new String ();
            uid = sendMessage(final_jid , m_Text);                            
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
});
```

**example.cpp:**

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_org_qtproject_example_myapplication_MiniXmppService_sendMessage(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring jid, jstring message)
{
std::string sjid;
jstrToStdStr(env, jid, sjid);

if (g_bot)
{
    CMessageSession *session = g_bot->getOutgoingSessionForJid(sjid);

    if (session)
    {
        std::string smessage;
        jstrToStdStr(env, message, smessage);
        g_bot->m_mutexClient.lock();
        jstring res = env->NewStringUTF(session->session->send(smessage).c_str());
        g_bot->m_mutexClient.unlock();
        return res;
    }
}

return env->NewStringUTF("uid-*-*");
}
```

And I got an error:
**non-static method sendMessage(String,String) cannot be referenced from a static context**

How to fix it?

Comment: Use `public static String sendMessage(String jid, String message);` instead. Or create a object and then use the method.

Comment: @UmaKanth How to create an object and then use the method?

Comment: is sendMessage declare in `Example.java` ?

Comment: @Blackbelt No , it declare on example.cpp

Comment: the `public native` I mean

Comment: @Blackbelt yes it is.